# Disable or remove all links to MySite?

Tags: my-site

We've just enabled MySite in my organization and all the author links etc. (user-related links) points towards their respective MySite. Is it possible to disable the links or remove them completely?

Comment: can you describe in more detail what you are looking for?  Do you want to remove the MySites feature or are you looking for different functionality when somebody clicks on a user's name?

Comment: I want to keep all the features but I want to "hide" all the links that points to MySite. Easily put: I wanna get rid of all the hrefs to MySite. Anyway I can modify the links would be awesome as I'm thinking about adding a modal popup whenever someone clicks on a user to get their contact info etc but that's in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you will need to find a way to change the behavior of the UserDisp.aspx page that is stored in the _layouts directory.  This is what is actually linked on the page, and then it will dynamically redirect them to the Person.aspx page within the User Profiles if it is deployed.

Sending them to the user profile is normally the desired result.

An alternative, "hackish" approach would be to include a user control in the master page that replaces or kills any link to the UserDisp.aspx page.

Comment: I actually ended upp uninstalling the MySite feature, which proved to be quite helpful. I still have all the functionality that I need and now I'm gonna work on changing the UserDisp.aspx file to suit my needs more. Thx, again, for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

In Central Administration, goto the User Profile Service Application.  Under People, select "Manage User Permissions".  That is where you can choose who can use social features, thus hiding it from people who do not have permission to use social features.

Comment: I've already done this and afaik all this does is to stop ppl from creating their MySites but the links to MySite is still there in every username etc.